# multiple when conditions cause my context menu items to hide

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've created a context menu with a couple of menu items like so:

```json
"contributes": {
        "commands": [{
                "command": "imageOptimizer.losslessOptimization",
                "title": "Lossless Optimization"
            }, {
                "command": "imageOptimizer.lossyOptimization",
                "title": "Lossy Optimization"
            }],
        "menus": {
            "explorer/context": [{
                    "command": "imageOptimizer.losslessOptimization",
                    "group": "7_modification",
                    "when": "resourceIsFile || explorerResourceIsFolder"
                }, {
                    "command": "imageOptimizer.lossyOptimization",
                    "group": "7_modification",
                    "when": "resourceIsFile || explorerResourceIsFolder"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

The context menu items show up fine when I don't use a when condition but when I try to use the two conditions shown here it hides both of them. What I was trying to do was make it so that these menu items only show up in the context menu if you have selected a file or folder. It does this by default but they also show up if you right click in the whitespace below all the files which is something I don't want. Are multiple when conditions allowed? If so how am I using them wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** starting with VSCode 1.37 / the July 2019 release, [`||` conditions in `when` clauses are supported](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_37#_support-for-or-in-when-clauses).

---

`when` does not support `||` yet, only `&&`:

[Add support for OR in package.json when clauses (#33547)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/33547)

Concerning your particular use case... are you sure you don't want to show the items when clicking on whitespace? Technically, that's still selecting a folder: the workspace folder itself. That's how VSCode's own built-in context menu items behave, and it's quite convenient that you can e.g. open the workspace folder by selecting "Reveal in Explorer" on empty space:

[image]